# POCO websocket exception

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I need to create a `WebSocket` communication between a C++ server and an angular client. I used the POCO library and the *websocket server* example. I managed to exchange data between the server and the client.

My problem is that when I update the web page (F5), the server closes.

What exception should I manage?

```
class WebSocketRequestHandler : public HTTPRequestHandler
    /// Handle a WebSocket connection.
{
public:
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();
        try
        {
            WebSocket ws(request, response);
            app.logger().information("WebSocket connection established.");
            char buffer[1024];

        do
        {

        n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags); 

            cout << buffer << endl;

        } while (n > 0 && (flags & WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BITMASK) != WebSocket::FRAME_OP_CLOSE);

        app.logger().information("WebSocket connection closed.");

    }
    catch (WebSocketException& exc)
    {
        app.logger().log(exc);
        switch (exc.code())
        {
        case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION:
            response.set("Sec-WebSocket-Version", WebSocket::WEBSOCKET_VERSION);

        case WebSocket::WS_ERR_NO_HANDSHAKE:

        case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_VERSION:

        case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_KEY:

        response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        response.setContentLength(0);
        response.send();
        break; 
        }
    }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also catch `Poco::Exception` in my application. It works well, no crash:

```
catch (WebSocketException& exception)
{
    switch (exception.code())
    {
    case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION:
        response.set("Sec-WebSocket-Version", WebSocket::WEBSOCKET_VERSION);
        // No break, fall through
    case WebSocket::WS_ERR_NO_HANDSHAKE:
    case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_VERSION:
    case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_KEY:
        response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        response.setContentLength(0);
        response.send();
        break;
    }
}
catch (Poco::Exception& exception)
{
    _logger.error("[%s] handle request {%s}", caller(), exception.displayText());
}
```